# What kind of coordinates are this ones?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I have to map a point using this coordinates:

38 R MF 18852 15799

I can't understand the coordinate system.

For sure '38' is the UTM zone number and 'R' is the designation (indicating southern Iraq)... but the rest?

Comment: Looks like the leading digits are stripped off. Can you identify the point in lat/lon? MGRS might fit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system

Comment: Thanks Andre. Unfortunately I have no idea about where this point is precisely, I only know that it is in southern Iraq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These coordinates are expressed in Military Grid Reference System (MGRS). Thanks Andre for the hint!